# Gmail api - credential storing

Tags: gmail-api, google-oauth

On the one-time process to get credentials for gmail api, a directory on file system must to be supplied to store them on a json file (DATA_STORE_DIR).
I'm using gmail api for Java and i don't have chance to use file system from my app to store that json file. 
Is there any other way to store credentials (e.g. database)?
Otherwise, should I provide my own impelmentation of FileDataStoreFactory class?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing credentials in database is possible, but you will need to create both a DataStore class extending com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStore, and a DataStoreFactory class extending com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStoreFactory.

I would suggest following the pattern of the existing AbstractMemoryDataStore.